# How to join multi condition query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

apt table

| unique_id | apt_name | apt_data | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Jose | Michigan | Active |
| 2222 | Michael | Michigan | Offline |
| 3333 | Mike | Canada | Active |

book table

| conv_id | apt_uniqueid | user_uniqueid | conv_status | conv_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A2B | 1111 | 77777 | invalid | 1 |
| 3C4D | 2222 | 88888 | valid | 0 |
| 5E6F | 3333 | 99999 | valid | 0 |
| 7F8G | 1111 | 99999 | invalid | 1 |
| 5T8Y | 2222 | 99999 | invalid | 1 |

My Expected query is Every single apt account which `status 'Active'` and apt account which in book table `conv_status = 'invalid'` and `conv_data =  1`

Expected query when `user_uniqueid = '99999'`

| conv_id | unique_id | apt_name | apt_data | status | conv_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1111 | Jose | Michigan | Active | 0 |
| 0 | 3333 | Mike | Canada | Active | 0 |
| 7F8G | 1111 | Jose | Michigan | Active | 1 |
| 5T8Y | 2222 | Michael | Michigan | Offline | 1 |

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM apt WHERE sts = 'Active' 
        UNION
        SELECT apt.*, book.* 
        FROM book
        INNER JOIN apt ON book.apt_uniqueid = apt.unique_id
        WHERE conv_status = 'invalid' AND (user_uniqueid = {$_SESSION['unique_id']} AND conv_data = '1') ORDER BY unique_id DESC";
```

Comment: You are using union ? The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements. However, every SELECT statement within UNION must have the **same number of columns**, which I believe is not the case in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. It depends on the amount of data you want from tables.
> 2. Common Use joins are INNER , LEFT, RIGHT.
>
> Now if you want data from the mentioned tables, Then simply use :-

```
SELECT book.conv_id, apt.unique_id, apt.apt_name,apt.apt_data,apt.status,book.conv_status,
FROM book
INNER JOIN Customers ON book.apt_uniqueid=apt.unique_id
WHERE book.conv_status = 'invalid' AND book.user_uniqueid = {$_SESSION['unique_id']} AND book.conv_data = '1' ORDER BY apt.unique_id DESC";
```

[For more details:](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: it will not output users that status 'Active' and not fulfil book.conv_status = 'invalid' AND book.user_uniqueid = {$_SESSION['unique_id']} AND book.conv_data = '1' i need to get apt user which is "active" and that fulfil book.conv_status = 'invalid' AND book.user_uniqueid = {$_SESSION['unique_id']} AND book.conv_data = '1' even its duplicated @Sandeep

Comment: Ok as per your requirement 
 **let suppose your user_uniqueid = 99999;**
` SELECT book.conv_id, apt.unique_id, apt.apt_name,apt.apt_data,apt.status,book.conv_status,
FROM book
INNER JOIN Customers ON book.apt_uniqueid=apt.unique_id
WHERE book.conv_status = 'invalid' AND book.user_uniqueid = {$_SESSION['unique_id']} AND book.conv_data = '1' AND apt.status = 'Active' ORDER BY apt.unique_id DESC";`
Output will be:
7F8G  1111  99999  invalid  1

Comment: @AZISSOFYANPRASETYO according to your condition requirement, the output is only one..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use left join if it's working

```
$sql = "SELECT apt.unique_id,
apt.apt_name,
apt.apt_data,
apt.status,
book.conv_id,
book.apt_uniqueid,
book.user_uniqueid,
book.conv_status,
book.conv_data
FROM apt
LEFT JOIN book ON book.apt_unqieid = apt.unique_id
WHERE apt.status= 'ACTIVE' AND apt.unique_id = '$_SESSION['unique_']' AND 
book.conv_data = '1' ORDER BY apt.unique_id DESC
";
```